# Get API data to display in view - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, api, laravel

I have downloaded a small project on GitHub that uses the Halo 5 API. Right now if I type in a MY Gamer tag on the website, it will give me this response:

```
{"SpartanRank":114,"Xp":4291837,"TotalKills":12653,"TotalDeaths":10383,"Kd":1.218626601175,"GamesWon":480}
```

I want to display them individually in a view for example, not in json format.

This is the 3 methods I have right now:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface;


use App\User;
use GuzzleHttp;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ImageController extends Controller {


    public function generate(Request $request) {


        // Validate email and password.
        $this->validate($request, [
            'gamertag' => 'required|min:3',
        ]);

        $gamertag = Input::get('gamertag');

        // Get data from API
        $playerStats = $this->getPlayerStats($gamertag);
        $playerArray = $this->getPlayerArray($playerStats);              

         $spartanRank = json_decode($playerArray['SpartanRank'], true);
    $XP = json_decode($playerArray['Xp'], true);
    $TotalKills = json_decode($playerArray['TotalKills'], true);
    $TotalHeadshots = json_decode($playerArray['TotalHeadshots'], true);
    $TotalShotsFired = json_decode($playerArray['TotalShotsFired'], true);
    $TotalDeaths = json_decode($playerArray['TotalDeaths'], true);
    $Kd = json_decode($playerArray['Kd'], true);
    $GamesWon = json_decode($playerArray['GamesWon'], true);


    return view('stats')
        ->with('spartanRank', $spartanRank)
        ->with('XP', $XP)
        ->with('TotalKills', $TotalKills)
        ->with('TotalShotsFired', $TotalShotsFired)
        ->with('TotalHeadshots', $TotalHeadshots)
        ->with('TotalDeaths', $TotalDeaths)
        ->with('Kd', $Kd)
        ->with('GamesWon', $GamesWon);

    }


   protected function getPlayerStats($gamertag) {

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/servicerecords/arena?players=' . $gamertag;

        $res = $client->request('GET', $baseURL, [
            'headers' => [
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'MY SECRET KEY HERE'
            ]
        ]);

        if($res->getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            return $result = json_decode($res->getBody());
        }

    }


   protected function getPlayerArray($playerStats) {
        $array = [];
        $array['SpartanRank'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->SpartanRank;
        $array['Xp'] =          $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->Xp;
        $array['TotalKills'] =  $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalKills;
        $array['TotalDeaths'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalDeaths;
        $array['Kd'] = $array['TotalKills'] / $array['TotalDeaths'];
        $array['GamesWon'] =    $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalGamesWon;

        return $array;
    }



}
```

And this is my view:

```
@extends('home')

@section('content')

    @include('pages.partials.nav')

   Spartan Rank: {{ $spartanRank }} <br>
Spartan XP: {{ $XP }}<br>
Total Kills: {{ $TotalKills }}<br>
Total Headshots: {{ $TotalHeadshots }}<br>
Total Shots Fired: {{ $TotalShotsFired }}<br>
Total Deaths: {{ $TotalDeaths }}<br>
KD: {{ $Kd }}<br>
Games Won: {{ $GamesWon }}<br>

@stop
```

So How do I display for example this {"TotalShotsFired"}, into a view like: Total Shots Fired: {{ $player->TotalShotsFired }} ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you see your json data at the top you have shown doesnt have any parent Key. so you can append it by:

```
return response()->json(array('player' => $array));
```

So you have something like:

```
{"player" :
     {
     "SpartanRank":114,
     "Xp":4291837,
     "TotalKills":12653,
     "TotalDeaths":10383,
     "Kd":1.218626601175,
     "GamesWon":480
     } 
}
```

Now you can access the array in view simply by typing :

```
{{ $player->TotalKills }}
```

Comment: Where is $array coming from because its giving me error for that?

Comment: You need to do something like this : $array = {"SpartanRank":114,"Xp":4291837,"TotalKills":12653,"TotalDeaths":10383,"Kd":1.218626601175,"GamesWon":480} and then pass this $array to 'player' => $array.

Comment: I got it working, check what i did at the bottom of generate method and in vie

Comment: Yes thats one way or you can store those data in a $array and pass it like return view ('view.name', 'array' => $array) But I am happy you got it working.. :)

Comment: Please vote if you think my solution helped in anyway ;)